# How to redirect, with Spring Security, a logged user to his front page and a non logged one to a different one

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm doing a Spring web-application project as a final project for school. We use SpringBoot with Hibernate and an H2 database. In order to authenticate and authorize, we use Spring Security. We also use the model View-Controller with repositories, services, and controllers.
I have an initial front page `(with the URL "/")` that is shown when you open the project. Once you log-in, you're redirected to another front page with the URL ("/portadaUsuario")(I'm from Spain so there's a lot of names in Spanish). But, if you somehow end up in the ("/") URL after you've logged in, you're shown the same front page that is shown to non-logged users with the sign-up and log-in options, which is obviously wrong.

I know that I can show different HTML elements with spring security tags and elements, but I've already built my project around having two different front-pages and I would like to keep it that way if possible. If it isn't achievable, please let me know how should I proceed to show different elements in the same HTML file.

Here are the methods of my WellcomeController

```
@Controller
public class PortadaController {

    @GetMapping({"/"})
    public String mostrarPortada() {
        return "portada";
    }

    @GetMapping("/portadaUser")
    public String mostrarPortadaUsuario() {
        return "/usuario/portada";
    }
}
```

Here are the methods that authenticate the users

```
@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/webjars/**", "/h2-console/**", "/", "/newUser/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .successHandler(customSuccessHandler)
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/portadaUser")
                        .and()
                .logout()
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .permitAll()
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedPage("/acceso-denegado");


        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
```

What I want is the application detecting when a logged user is requesting the "/" URL, and for it to be redirected to `/portadaUser` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you have two pages, one for signed in (signed-in-home) and another for not signed in(not-signed-in-home), you code something like this -

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Principal principal, Model model) {
   return principal != null ? "signed-in-home" : "not-signed-in-home";
}
```

Read more about principal here- https://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security

Answer (score 0):

Tested in jsp + Spring 4.3.13 + Spring Security 4.2.11

1.checked in **jsp**

"<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>"

```
<script>
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
        location.replace('/yourpage')
    </sec:authorize>
</script>
```

2. checked in **controller**
**SpringSecurityUtil.class**

```
 public class SpringSecurityUtil {

        public static boolean hasRole(String role) {
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<GrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
            boolean hasRole = false;
            for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
                if(authority.getAuthority().equals(role)) {
                    hasRole = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return hasRole;
        }

    }
```

**HomeController.class**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(HttpServletResponse resp) {
        if(SpringSecurityUtil.hasRole("ADMIN"))
            //if has role send your page
        else
            //if has not role send your page
    }
}
```

3. add antMatchers in your Spring Security Config class.

```
antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
```

4. use @PreAuthority

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
}
```

**HomeController.class**

```
 @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String home() {
              //If this code starts, you have ADMIN privileges.
        }
    }
```

see more [Spring Security Method Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-method)